# How to extract between keywords using batch

Tags: batch-file

If you'll don't mind I need help with an extraction script I have 
This script works great and fast as long as my txt file is under 100K lines 
The file I tested has 60K lines and is a Json format 
 and it works great 
but when I tested it on a txt file over 500K txt file it took a very long time, 
to where I just closed out the the CMD window

I need help to find a better way to improve the script to extract content from a txt file over 500K lines

Here is my Script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

SET "sourcedir=%~dp0New folder 1"
SET "destdir=%~dp0New folder 2"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "name"^<"%sourcedir%\nsb.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "caow"^<"%sourcedir%\nsb.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\nsb.txt" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\(1).txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

This is a small part of the files content

```
  {
  "name": 6,
  "agprlv": 0,
  "las": "ACTIVE",
  "gdprcs": "Consented",
  "gdprcds": true,
  "gdprcpv": 2,
  "ccpacltc": 0,
  "ccpacs": false,
  "ccpaoov": "control",
  "pdcs": false,
  "moptinfcs": 0,
  "moptinnour": false,
  "moptintlact": -1,
  "boqt": 4.033,
  "boht": 6.819,
  "tdtr": 43026170.0,
  "tplt": 184592,
  "tgrt": 126002,
  "dbdt": 1,
  "dbla": 89,
  "dbir": 429,
  "dblt": 1648640442000,
  "odbct": "03/30/2022 11:41:10",
  "mgpl": 50654349249,
  "mgat": 0,
  "lblt": "05/18/2022 05:00:00",
  "lbct": "04/06/2022 05:00:00",
  "cert": "05/14/2022 00:00:00",
  "lpff": "12/31/9999 23:59:59",
  "caow": [
    {
```

I wish I could share the whole txt file but I can't 
the current text file has 566857 lines 
My files are in three parts
top half starts at 1 ends at 20K 
middle part start at 20001 and ends at 460K 
bottom half starts at 460001 and at 566K

I know other scripts like python will do this job very easy but my whole work station works around batch scripts so I'm trying to keep it to batch

Any Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use PowerShell which fully supports JSON, not internal cmd.exe commands, which do not.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but we got a batch script working total time to extract 1 minute

Comment: @Compo: I don't know enough PowerShell to know what is the code to perform this extraction of a range of fields. Or, it must be performed via a loop? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments about your code:

- Try to execute as less operations as possible. You execute two `IF` commands *in each line* of the big file!
- The `FOR /F` command first execute the commands and store in a temporary file *all the output*. If the output is large, additional buffers needs to be allocated, etc. When the output command ends, FOR /F start to output its data from the temporary file out. Corollary: never use FOR /F command on big files.

Try this solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "sourcedir=%~dp0New folder 1"
SET "destdir=%~dp0New folder 2"

set "skip="
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"') do (
   if not defined skip (
      set /A "skip=%%a-1"
   ) else (
      set /A "copy=%%a-skip+1"
   )
)

< "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt" (

   rem Skip undesired lines at beginning
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%skip%) do set /P "="

   rem Copy desired lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%copy%) do (
      set /P "line="
      echo(!line!
   )

) > "%destdir%\(1).txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Please, report the timing...

Comment: Please, report the output of this command: `findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"`. It _should be_ the lines of "name" and "caow" tags...

Comment: No. Execute this command from the command prompt: `findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"`. The output _must be_ just 2 lines: the lines with "name" and "caow". If not, then there is a problem with your data...

Comment: Make a new script with just two lines: the `findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"` one and `pause` in second line.  Then, run it and report the output...

Comment: Excuse me. I couldn't help you if you don't help me to detect the problem...

Comment: I suppose that your data file have _more than one line_ with `"caow"` value! However, if you don't confirm this point, I can't fix my code... **`:(`**

Comment: Mmm... I think I could not help you because you don't give me the feedback I requested before in order to help you... I asked you _3 times_ ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025549/how-to-extract-between-keywords-using-batch/75026569?noredirect=1#comment132399481_75026569), the next comment below it, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025549/how-to-extract-between-keywords-using-batch/75026569?noredirect=1#comment132399581_75026569) ) that you execute `findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"` and you just ignored me...

Comment: Ok. If you answered to _my request_ as you said (not what you think I should know, but a simple and clear request: execute `findstr /N "name caow" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"`), please, tell me where are the output of such `findstr` command... I invite you to read the comments above again before you answer this...

Comment: Not sure where you want me to report the output - but I added more stuff to my answer I posted below - if that is not what you want to see - then I have no idea what you are asking - if I got it wrong well then thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set up the extraction between 2 words

```bash
    @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    
    SET "sourcedir=%~dp0New folder 1"
    SET "destdir=%~dp0New folder 2"
    
    set "skip="
    for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "<\name\>" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"') do (
       if not defined skip (
          set /A "skip=%%a-1"
       ) else (
          set /A "copy=%%a-skip"
       )
    )
    for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "<\caow\>" "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt"') do (
       if not defined skip (
          set /A "skip=%%a"
       ) else (
          set /A "copy=%%a-skip-1"
       )
    )
    
    < "%sourcedir%\nsb.txt" (
    
       rem Skip undesired lines at beginning
       for /L %%i in (1,1,%skip%) do set /P "="
    
       rem Copy desired lines
       for /L %%i in (1,1,%copy%) do (
          set /P "line="
          echo(!line!
       )
    
    ) > "%destdir%\(1).txt"
    GOTO :EOF
```

after using the updated script above this where my results 
if your search is repeated like this `"name": or "funname"`
you can do this to lock it in `"<\name\>"`

But if you have two repeated words like this `"name":` and this `"name":` it will find either one and extract incorrectly

```bash
Output Results..... <br>

 {
  "name": 6,
  "agprlv": 0,
  "las": "ACTIVE",
  "gdprcs": "Consented",
  "gdprcds": true,
  "gdprcpv": 2,
  "ccpacltc": 0,
  "ccpacs": false,
  "ccpaoov": "control",
  "pdcs": false,
  "moptinfcs": 0,
  "moptinnour": false,
  "moptintlact": -1,
  "boqt": 4.033,
  "boht": 6.819,
  "tdtr": 43026170.0,
  "tplt": 184592,
  "tgrt": 126002,
  "dbdt": 1,
  "dbla": 89,
  "dbir": 429,
  "dblt": 1648640442000,
  "odbct": "03/30/2022 11:41:10",
  "mgpl": 50654349249,
  "mgat": 0,
  "lblt": "05/18/2022 05:00:00",
  "lbct": "04/06/2022 05:00:00",
  "cert": "05/14/2022 00:00:00",
  "lpff": "12/31/9999 23:59:59",

The script runs great but it also depends on the size of the file <br>
working on a 556K file it took 2 minutes to extract data and again it depends on the size of the file <br>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://superuser.com/questions/1605009/windows-command-line-find-command-is-very-slow
^ Refer this if it helps ^

---

My Recommendation:
Try using `findstr` instead of the `find` that you used to search for strings. I saw in one article that its faster than the `find` command, as the find command is older and is slower.

Comment: I don't understand how your powershell command can be used to extract the lines between "name" and "caow", including they, as the OP requested ("extract between keywords"). Could you better explain this point?

Comment: I figured `findster` was the answer - but was not sure how to convert my script to findster

Comment: replace the `find` command that you used in your script with `findstr` and Keep other scripts the same. It should work, try it.

Comment: @Aacini - why is it that the script fails when I do a search like this `"isra1": 1,`  - I noticed that this fails `: 1`  - I made a few changes during my testing and I was able make a few test work, I did this `for /F "tokens= 3, 1delims=:"` to make this `"isra1" ` work